# After resizing the window, elements within do no fit anymore

Tags: javascript, html

I have a modal dialog (window.showModalDialog) with html in it. when I resize the dialog, the HTML within it does not repect the new boundaries and I get scroll bars or elements that don't expand 100% to the new width.

To fix this I have to drag it around for a bit and it then jolts it self back into the correct sizes.

To fix it programtically. I do the following `window.document.getElementById('removeMainBody').innerHTML =window.document.getElementById('removeMainBody').innerHTML;`

But this causes some dynamic objects in the html to stop functionin.

How can i solve this problem and make the elemnts within the dialog resize after I resize the dialog?

Here is my code

```
 else if(<c:out value="${staffCount}" /> > 1){
            document.getElementById('removeDiv').style.display = '';
            window.dialogWidth='770px';
            window.dialogHeight='320px';
            window.document.getElementById('removeMainBody').innerHTML =window.document.getElementById('removeMainBody').innerHTML;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a style or a Class from the Body-Tag, this should force an HTML Reflow, and the Site would be displayed correct again, without setting the innerHTML Property.

```
example:

...
window.document.body.className = "relfow"; 
// if the body class Attribute was set, than set it now back
window.document.body.className = "oldBodyStyleClassName" ; / Or just to ""
...
```

if the browser optimizes, the refresh calls, so that now reflow occures you could

```
setTimeout(function(){
...
window.document.body.className = "relfow"; 
// if the body class Attribute was set, than set it now back
window.document.body.className = "oldBodyStyleClassName" ; / Or just to ""
...
})
```

i hope this helps. (here you can find some info to Reflow [Link](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow))

Comment: thanks. after googling reflow it turned out this doesnt work for ie6 but `element.parentNode.style.overflow = "hidden";` did the job